# Convert String to java.sql.Date and java.sql.Time

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc

If I have a method like this:

```
public static String convertDateTimeToString(DateTime dt) {
    return dt.getDate() + " " + dt.getTime();
}
```

Which takes a `DateTime` object of my own which contains a `java.sql.Date` and a `java.sql.Time`, what is the best way of reversing the process so that I can substring a `java.sql.Date` and a `java.sql.Time` from a String?

Or if `DateTime dt` is a JodaTime `DateTime` object?

If this can be done without reference to `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 9):

Look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class. Here's a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

You'll need something like this:

```
String datetimeString;
Date result;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d MMM yy hh:mm:ss");
result = formatter.parse (datetimeString);
```

Comment: Thanks. The only issue I have with this is that Date result appears to be Java.util.date whereas I need Java.sql.date and Java.sql.time.

Comment: @Mr Morgan: but it's not a problem at all. You can create sql.Date instance easily: `java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(result.getTime());`.

Comment: Well, it seems to work as follows: String datetimeString = "2010-05-23 23:32:45"; Date result; SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); result = formatter.parse (datetimeString); java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(result.getTime()); java.sql.Time sqlTime = new java.sql.Time(result.getTime()); System.out.println("SQL date " + sqlDate + " " + sqlTime); Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [valueOf](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) method of java.sql.Time to convert a String into a java.sql.Time, and use the [valueOf](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) method of java.sql.Date to convert a String into a java.sql.Date