# Converting a String of java.sql.Date format to a String of java.util.date format

Tags: java, date

I am trying to convert sql date string to normal date, but I am getting this exception

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-03-11"
>       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.ninenexus.simplesignworkflow.Task.getTaskDetails(Task.java:1385)
>       at org.apache.jsp.task_jsp._jspService(task_jsp.java:259)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I want like this

From `"2013-03-11"` to `"11/03/2013"`
how can i FIX it?

Comment: [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) ***is*** a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Post your code how you are trying to convert. As per the exception it seems your format is wrong.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980583/how-to-convert-string-to-java-sql-date-and-java-sql-time

Comment: i am fetching date from database, and converting it to normal.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy).format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2013-03-11"))`?

Comment: You're saying you're fetching a `java.sql.Date` `String` - That's not possible

Comment: Try [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: i am trying to implement suggestions.

Comment: ok then simply tell me how can i convert this "2013-03-11"  to normal Date 11-03-2013

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is simply unreasonable.

First, java.sql.Date is already a java.util.Date.

Second, java.sql.Date is NOT a SQL date string.  Both java.sql.Date and java.util.Date has nothing to do with the format how the date is going to be displayed.  i.e. There is no such thing as a Date containing "2013-03-11" while another Date containing "11/03/2013".

Answer (score 3):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
String text = df.format(date);  

System.out.println("The date is: " + text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it in this way:

```java
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = df.parse("2013-03-11");   // convert string to date
df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
// date formatted in whatever format you want. 
System.out.println("The date is: " + df.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a help of `SimpleDateFormat` class and `parse` date string to get `Util Date object`.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

    public class DateConverter {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

            String dateString = "03/04/2013";
            Date utiDate;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            utiDate = dateFormater.parse (dateString);
            System.out.println(utiDate);
        }
    }
```