# Convert String to SQL Date

Tags: java, string, date, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a `String` which contains date string eg 12-28-18 of format MM-dd-yy. I wish to pass this parameter to a stored procedure in Oracle database.

Hence, I am trying to convert this String to `java.sql.Date`. Following is the method I am following to convert:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
java.util.Date date1 = df.parse(valueobject.getDate());
java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime())
```

However , it leads to `ParseException`.
Not able to figure out why it fails during parsing.
Any help on this would be great!

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy", Locale.English);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980583/how-to-convert-string-to-java-sql-date-and-java-sql-time

Comment: @johnchen902 Adding the locale does not work!

Comment: Tried this: `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse("12-28-18");` but no exception thrown.

Comment: Is `valueobject.getDate()` a String? Just to double check. I've seen someone accidentally try to parse a date into a date.

Comment: @MarkM Yes its a String for sure..anyway thanks

Answer (score 6):

Using **`valueOf()`**:

```
String date = "2000-11-01"; // YYYY-MM-DD
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM-dd-yy hh:mm:ss");
    Date d=new Date();
    String date1 = df.format(d);
    java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(df.format(date2));
```

Or

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
    Date d=new Date();
    String date1 = df.format(d);
    java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
    System.out.println(date1);
    System.out.println(df.format(date2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, maybe your`valueobject.getDate()` doesn't return a String. Please check!!

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date parsed = format.parse("07-15-2013");
    java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
```

Similar with your code and work very well!